# Codeigniter - Having trouble with printing a web page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

I have a web page(INVOICE) which is looks like this

[image]

I had used html, css and php to create this page. 
I am printing this page from java script with

```
windows.print();
```

this whole page is in TABLE tag. when the content is more than one page the page look like this, I need a border-bottom when two page breaks, 
please help me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Read about page breaks in css. They could lead you into the right path.

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/

also read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8712756/406659

```
<style type="text/css">
   table { page-break-inside:auto }
   tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I had use page break which works perfectly in Firefox but not in Chrome,so need another solution for that

Comment: seamsto work in chrome 30+ but if not look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25367919/406659