# PHP Print preview problems for table

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, report

I am generating a php report from Mysql DB. Everything I display in this report is fetched from database.

**The problem I face in print preview**

1. If table 3 expands, table4 breaks into two half and sits on next page
   2.If I use `table-header-group;` as Headers for table5, table1 & table 3, its not working in browsers.

**Solution I needed**

1.If table3 row increases, if table 4 touches the below line(div border),it should completely move to next page in print preview.

2.If table4 goes to next page, it should come below table1 & 2.

**Need Help!**

[image: Report Sample Image]

**My Code:**

```
    @media print {
        #container
        {
        border:1px solid;
        }
        table
        {
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;

        border-spacing:0;
        border-collapse: collapse; 

        }

        table td 
        {
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 1mm;
        }

        table.heading
        {
        height:50mm;
        }

        #table_table3, #table_table4
        {   
        font-size: 9pt;
    line-height: 7px;font-size: 9pt;
page-break-before: always;
        }
        #table_table3 table , #table_table4 table
        {
        width:100%;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        font-size: 9pt
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse; 
    page-break-before: always;
        //margin-top:5mm;
        }

        #table_table3 table td , #table_table4 table td
        {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:9pt;
        border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding:1mm 0;
page-break-before: always;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Also: I really don't think tables are the best choice here. The layout, to me at least, seems to beg for divs to be used

Comment: This is an html/css issue. The fact it's using php or mysql has no relevance.

Comment: ok,How to stop table4 break between page1 and page 2

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some `@media print` rules to your CSS, so that you get a printer friendly style.

For instance:

Prevent headings from being printed at the bottom of the page

```
h2, h3 {
   page-break-after: avoid;
}
```

Prevent list splits or in-image splits

```
ul, img {
   page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Always page-break before table and articles

```
table, article {
   page-break-before: always;
}
```

Page break before specifc table:

```
table#table-4 {
   page-break-before: always;
}

<table id="table-4">...</table>
```

In some browsers this works:

```
table { page-break-inside:auto }
tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
thead { display:table-header-group }
tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
```

Referencing:

- [How to apply CSS page-break to print a table with lots of rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8712677/1163786)

**Warning. Severe Browser incompatibilities ahead.**

Seems like the majority of browsers do not care about the page-break-* rules..

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/page-break-before
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/page-break-inside
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/page-break-after

Looks like, Opera is the only one supporting this..

Spec is http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html

Comment: I added `@media print {table4 {
   page-break-before: always;
}` ,its not working

Comment: Ok, updated the code to reference the table by it's id.

Comment: Please see above. I added the updated code with reference to your suggestions.

Comment: The majority of browsers do not care about the page-break-* rules.. this seems to work only in Opera.