# Is it possible to force a page-break inside an unordered list?

Tags: html, css

I have written a menu for an Italian restaurant. This menu consists of an unordered list where each li element has a class named "headline". Each of these li elements contains a headline  and another ul inside with li-s as dishes.

It looks like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="headline">
      <h3>Kind of dishes</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Dish 1</li>
        <li>Dish 2</li>
        <li>Dish 3</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="headline">
      <h3>Another kind of dishes</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Dish 1</li>
        <li>Dish 2</li>
        <li>Dish 3</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to make a printable version of the menu and have no clue why either "page-break-after" nor "page-break-before" work on ".headline" in CSS.

I tried different display values like "block", "inline-block", or "table-row", because reading certain forums suggested it. I also tried different position values ("absolute","relative","static")...

I also tried to wrap the "headline" li-s with div elements and use page-break on the div elements:

```html
<ul>
  <div>
  <li class="headline">
      <h3>Kind of dishes</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Dish 1</li>
        <li>Dish 2</li>
        <li>Dish 3</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  </div>
  <div>
  <li class="headline">
      <h3>Another kind of dishes</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Dish 1</li>
        <li>Dish 2</li>
        <li>Dish 3</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

I start to believe that my only option is to re-think the unordered list concept or deliver a pdf-file on print-demand...

I think I would have chose the second method, because I use the li-s to toggle the ul-s in the mobile version.

Is there a fundamental error I do not see yet, or is it simply not possible to control where page breaks are done in unordered lists?

Edit:
I tried different suggenstions of the "possible duplicate thread" and all what it does (I don't know if I am right there and can explain it properly) is that it tries to make page-breaks...

It generates space between the "headline" li-s containing the ul-s... Unfortunately the blank spaces appear in the middle of the pages (print preview and saved pdf) and have a certain height... so it doesn't really push the "headline" li-s on the next page... just slightly down wherever a "headline"li ends

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS page-break to print a table with lots of rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712677/how-to-apply-css-page-break-to-print-a-table-with-lots-of-rows)

Comment: Thank you! I will try this tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
page-break-inside: avoid;
break-inside: avoid;
```

Add break-inside: avoid; to ul

Comment: Thank you! I will try this tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem adding `page-break-after: always` to the `li`. It was fixed by adding a `div` inside with `page-break-after: always` followed by an empty `div`. It works on both Edge and IE11 as well as on Chrome (not yet tested on Firefox).

Amending your example, it should look like the following:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="headline">
      <h3>Kind of dishes</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Dish 1</li>
        <li>Dish 2</li>
        <li>Dish 3</li>
      </ul>
      <div style="page-break-after: always"></div>
      <div></div>
  </li>
  <li class="headline">
      <h3>Another kind of dishes</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Dish 1</li>
        <li>Dish 2</li>
        <li>Dish 3</li>
      </ul>
      <div style="page-break-after: always"></div>
      <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note: Do not repeat the `page-break-after` in your `headline` class.