# CSS Print Table Break Inside with Border

Tags: html, css, printing, border, page-break

I want to add border in the middle of table break when printing, is it possible? I've search everywhere but found nothing.

Table `header/footer` or `page-break-inside: avoid;` is not helping at all, because the table will just not break and leave so much empty space, like this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

So i want it still break-inside but with border on top and bottom for every page, like this:

[image: Screenshot 2]

To something like this:

[image: Screenshot 3]

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table class="print-friendly">
    <!-- The rest of your table here -->
</table>

<style>
table.print-friendly tr td, table.print-friendly tr th {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
</style>
```

Most CSS rules don't apply to `<tr>` tags directly, because of exactly what you pointed out above - they have a unique `display` style, which doesn't allow for these CSS rules. However, the `<td>` and `<th>` tags within them usually do allow this kind of specification - and you can easily apply such rules to ALL child-`<tr>`'s and `<td>`'s using CSS as shown above.

**Credit goes to:** [Troy Alford](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874452)

---

**Other Sources:**

[avoid page break inside row of table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288802/avoid-page-break-inside-row-of-table)

[How to avoid splitting an HTML table across pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110591/how-to-avoid-splitting-an-html-table-across-pages)

[How to apply CSS page-break to print a table with lots of rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712677/how-to-apply-css-page-break-to-print-a-table-with-lots-of-rows)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-apply-css-page-break-to-print-a-table-with-lots-of-rows/

Comment: No, it's not about that, it still don't have border while page breaking, it should break but have border at the same time

Answer (score 0):

As a partial solution- we've added two divs.

First with

```
position:absolute;
top:0; /*some margin*/ 
bottom:0;/*some margin*/ 
left:0;
right:0;
border-top:1px solid #fff;
border-bottom:1px solid #000; 
z-index:1001;
```

And the second with

```
position:fixed;
top:0;/*some margin*/ 
bottom:0;/*some margin*/ 
left:0;
right:0;
border-top:1px solid #000;
border-bottom:1px solid #000; 
z-index:1000;
```

The second `div` is displayed on all pages, while the first one is displayed only on the first page. Because of lesser `z-index` the "fixed" `div`'s upper border is hidden. So the the first page was got rid of upper border, while others had the upper and the bottom borders. Still - we was unable to remove the bottom border on the last page and were forced to set up pdf footer to make it look nice

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and my search for a solution also came up completely empty. I was able to achieve the desired result by leveraging the fact that the table header and footer will be printed on every page. To implement this workaround, follow these steps:

1. Add a header and footer to the table, including empty cells for each column. Ensure that all table cells have borders, and use the border-collapse property to prevent additional padding.
2. Hide the extra borders created by the empty header and footer. For the header, only the top border is needed, so the bottom border can be hidden. In the first row, there's no need for a top border since it comes from the header. Apply a similar approach to the footer and the last row.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcEUT.png)

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/thebugsareinyourmind/pen/MWRaWZY)

CSS:

```
table, th, td {
    border: 5px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead th {            
    border-bottom: none;
}

tfoot th {
    border-top: none;
}

tbody tr:first-child td {
    border-top: none;
}

tbody tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
        </tr>                            
    </tbody>
</table>
```