# page-break-after / page-break-after property for div elements

Tags: html, css

My html is having this kind of structure :

```
<div>
    <div class="pagebr">content1</div>
    <div class="pagebr">content2</div>
    <div class="pagebr">content3</div>
    <div class="pagebr">content4</div>
    <div class="pagebr">content5</div>
    <div class="pagebr">content6</div>
    <div class="pagebr">content7</div>
</div>
```

All the inner `Div` elements are coming dynamically. Sometimes there will be one or two `div` or may be all. It is not fixed. But total are 7. 
When I write class -

```
div.pagebr
{
    page-break-after:always;   
}
```

Every div move to next new page creating empty space after `div` element. 
`page-break-before:always;` does the same and `page-break-after:auto;`  is not working anymore.

How should I add class for the Div elements, so that they can be fit on each page without breaking? Or is there any alternate solution?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: what do you really want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Page content can not be fit in a page in case of dynamic elements. If you want avoid page break inside your div you can specify `page-break-inside:avoid;` like following example

```css
div.pagebr
{
    page-break-inside:avoid;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="pagebr">content1</div>
    <div class="pagebr">content2</div>
    <div class="pagebr">content3</div>
    <div class="pagebr">content4</div>
    <div class="pagebr">content5</div>
    <div class="pagebr">content6</div>
    <div class="pagebr">content7</div>
</div>
```

**Alternative way**

If you want 3 `div`s inside a page then you could go with the following solution

To have a page braek in every 3 div you have to use selector `:nth-child(3n)` to give `page-break-after: always;`

```css
div.pagebr:nth-child(3n) {
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="pagebr">content1</div>
  <div class="pagebr">content2</div>
  <div class="pagebr">content3</div>
  <div class="pagebr">content4</div>
  <div class="pagebr">content5</div>
  <div class="pagebr">content6</div>
  <div class="pagebr">content7</div>
</div>
```

To know more about more details about `page-break` go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8712756/6082645) and [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_page-break-after.htm) links