# CSS page-break on 2 pages div

Tags: html, css

Page does not break after a 2 pages div

Working fine with content in 1 page
[image: Working fine with content in 1 page]

Won't break if previous content is too long, dragged to page 2

[image: Won't break if previous content is too long, dragged to page 2]

I put

`<div class="pagebreak"></div>`

at the end of each of my tickets with style:

`.pagebreak { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:always; }`

Work fine with 1 page but long document it wont break.

Please help me to break them to correctly page.

Comment: Provide a proper [mcve], please. _“I put `<div class="pagebreak"></div>`at the end of each of my tickets”_ - probably that is your mistake already; you should not put this “at the end” of the thing you don’t want to break, but the thing _itself_ should get those properties set. (Think for a second about why that property might be named page-break-_inside_ …)

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712677/how-to-apply-css-page-break-to-print-a-table-with-lots-of-rows

Comment: @misorude I want to BREAK right after the table, which is the end of my ticket. It worked like the first image.
But second image, the table is a bit long to next page. It wont break.

Comment: Before you discuss this any further, please do as you were asked to, and provide a proper example!

Comment: I put it on fiddle, 1 long and 3 shorts https://jsfiddle.net/ghqxzrkb/1/

Answer (score -1):

your css

```
.pagebreak { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:always; }
```

have you ever tried this instead ?

```
.pagebreak { page-break-inside:always; page-break-after:always; }
```

keep me up to date about your problem