# Create new DIN A4 if table row reached the end of the page

Tags: html, angular, printing, wysiwyg, page-break

I have created a container that has the size of a DIN A4 in he mode "screen". In that container I fill the formular with data and want to generate a new page under the previous page, if the new row doesnt fit in the previous page anymore. My goal is to print the formular like WYSIWYG. I am using angular as framework.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class"card">
      <form ....>
          <table>
             <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let element of elements.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
                    table content that can expands. If this reach the max of the DIN A4 height it should do a "page-break"
                </tr>
             </tbody>
          </table>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.invoice-container {
   width: 210 mm;
   ming-height: 297; 

   .card {
       ...
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: The layout from this page looks like mine: https://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/LFAes

Comment: I found this also interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712677/how-to-apply-css-page-break-to-print-a-table-with-lots-of-rows

Comment: This is the best way how I want it: http://jsfiddle.net/2wk6Q/1/
only my "card" should be repeatable if max reached. I try with ng-repeat