# How to force page breaks inside of a table when printing

Tags: reactjs, printing, page-break, react-to-print

I have a problem with the table border not being perfect if the page is more than 1, here is a picture of the print preview results:

[image]

[Here's the sample code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/remix-react-to-print-zj3wy9)

I hope the table between the page spacing has a border.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712677/how-to-apply-css-page-break-to-print-a-table-with-lots-of-rows